# How to scroll a single column content without moving others column?

Tags: layout, scroll, grid

Suppose, I have 3 columns. I want to add different type content into the columns. Then I want to scroll single columns without scrolling others column (As like Facebook)? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 3 containers next to each other- it is possible. If table with 3 columns- I think not possible without rewriting.

So for 3 separate divs- make them inline-block (prevent next line) and add width. Set the overflow to auto. You can also add the height.

Ugly snippet follows.

```css
    #left {
    width:30vw;
    height:100vh;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;
    }

    #center {
    width:30vw;
    height:100vh;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;
    }
    #right {
    width:30vw;
    height:100vh;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="left">
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    left <br>left <br>left <br>left <br>more left <br>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
    center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    more center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    some more center </br>center </br>center </br>

    center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    more center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    some more center </br>center </br>center </br>
    center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    more center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>center </br>
    some more center </br>center </br>center </br>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
    right <br>right <br>right <br>more right <br>right <br>right <br>
    right <br>more right <br>right <br>right <br>right <br>
    more right <br>right <br>right <br>right <br>more right <br>
    right <br>right <br>right <br>more right <br>right <br>
    right <br>right <br>more right <br>right <br>right <br>
    more right <br>right <br>right <br>right <br>more right <br>
    right <br>right <br>right <br>more right <br>right <br>
    right <br>right <br>more right <br>right <br>
    right <br>right <br>more right <br>
    </div>
```

Comment: its helpful for me! can i make this type using grid?

Comment: Grid should be possible too. As long as the width of element is fixed and the height of the element is more than the predefined- it should cause the element scrollbars to appear (when element overflows). The scrollbars can be hidden with CSS while scrolling is still enabled. Forgot the property to hide them, but you can google it.

Comment: The scrollbars can be hidden with CSS while scrolling is still enabled. The example at the end of https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp should work.